# filter content with categories and keywords in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, filtering, categories

I am having a pretty big problem I have the following code and I have buttons to try to filter videos based on what category or keyword they have associated with them. However I am getting duplicates in the filter method I wrote. to make matters worse some of the content doesn't even display.

I have the following variables in my data property

```
data :{
loggedIn: true,
displayCount:36,
searchQuery:'',
templateArray:[],
filteredTemplateArray:[],
categories: [],
keywords:[],
selectedCategories:[],
selectedKeywords:[], 
sortBy:''
},
```

when thea page loads templateArray and filteredTemplateArray are both equal to

> [{"id":"7","itemId":"17520","itemName":"Arrow
>   Bounce","thumbName":"ARROWBOUNCE","dateAdded":"2016-05-20
>   16:33:42","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/ArrowBounce-Scott/arrowBounce.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":["LensFlare"]},{"id":"11","itemId":"38752","itemName":"Jitter
>   Zoom Flash","thumbName":"JITTERZOOMFLASH","dateAdded":"2016-05-23
>   13:49:03","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/JitterZoomFlash-Scott/JitterZoomFlash.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":["Sports"],"keywordArray":["Snow","Sparkles"]},{"id":"12","itemId":"12737","itemName":"Cloth
>   Drop","thumbName":"CLOTHDROP","dateAdded":"2016-05-23
>   14:11:42","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/ClothDrop-Scott/cloth
>   drop.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"15","itemId":"73076","itemName":"Colorful
>   Trans","thumbName":"COLORFULIMAGETRANS","dateAdded":"2016-05-27
>   10:16:56","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/ColorfulImageTrans-Scott/ColorfulImageTrans.aep","stillImageLocation":"12.90","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":["Water","Sparkles"]},{"id":"16","itemId":"18488","itemName":"Convex
>   ½
>   Circle","thumbName":"CONVEXHALFCIRCLE","dateAdded":"2016-05-27
>   10:38:20","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/convexHalfCircle-Scott/convex
>   half
>   circle.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"17","itemId":"67039","itemName":"Flag
>   Swap","thumbName":"FLAGBACKSWAP","dateAdded":"2016-06-01
>   15:34:22","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/FlagBackSwap-Scott/FlagBackSwap.aep","stillImageLocation":"5.83","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"31","itemId":"70006","itemName":"Flag
>   Raise","thumbName":"FLAGRAISE","dateAdded":"2016-06-03
>   11:13:37","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/FlagRaise-Scott/flag.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"32","itemId":"58759","itemName":"Logo
>   Dust Poof","thumbName":"LOGODUSTPOOF","dateAdded":"2016-06-03
>   11:25:34","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/LogoDustPoof-Scott/LogoDustPoof.aep","stillImageLocation":"6.23","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"33","itemId":"58967","itemName":"Flag
>   Wave (Loop)","thumbName":"FLAGWAVE","dateAdded":"2016-06-03
>   11:35:49","renderTime":"75","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/FlagWave-Scott/FlagWave.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"34","itemId":"65288","itemName":"Logo
>   Splash One","thumbName":"LOGOSPLASHONE","dateAdded":"2016-06-03
>   15:34:19","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/LogoSplashOne-Scott/LogoSplashOne.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.70","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"35","itemId":"91246","itemName":"Metal
>   Sparks","thumbName":"METALSPARKS","dateAdded":"2016-06-06
>   10:58:29","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/MetalSparks-Scott/MetalSparks.aep","stillImageLocation":"4.63","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"36","itemId":"57489","itemName":"Middle
>   Stripe","thumbName":"MIDDLESTRIPEABA","dateAdded":"2016-06-06
>   12:25:41","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/MiddleStripe-Scott/middleStripeABA.aep","stillImageLocation":"6.80","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"37","itemId":"38402","itemName":"Water
>   One","thumbName":"WATERONE","dateAdded":"2016-06-07
>   09:10:32","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/waterOne-Scott/waterOne.aep","stillImageLocation":"8.83","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"39","itemId":"81031","itemName":"Oval
>   Text Flip","thumbName":"OVALTEXTFLIP","dateAdded":"2016-05-07
>   09:10:32","renderTime":"150","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/OvalTextFlip-Scott/OvalTextFlip.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"40","itemId":"55143","itemName":"Close
>   Up Text","thumbName":"CLOSEUPTEXT","dateAdded":"2016-07-05
>   09:10:32","renderTime":"85","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/CloseUpText-Scott/CloseUpText/CloseUpText.aep","stillImageLocation":"9.03","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"41","itemId":"54335","itemName":"Electric
>   Text Spin","thumbName":"ELECTRICTEXTSPIN","dateAdded":"2016-07-13
>   09:10:32","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/ElectricTextSpin-Scott/ElectricTextSpin/ElectricTextSpin.aep","stillImageLocation":"1.47","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"42","itemId":"23761","itemName":"Digital
>   Glitch","thumbName":"DIGITALGLITCH","dateAdded":"2016-09-19
>   09:10:32","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/DigitalGlitch-Scott/DigitalGlitch.aep","stillImageLocation":"3.43","categoryArray":["Retail"],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"43","itemId":"56465","itemName":"Takeover","thumbName":"TAKEOVER","dateAdded":"2016-09-30
>   14:10:32","renderTime":"80","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/TakeOver-Scott/TakeoverProject/takeoverproject.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"44","itemId":"17127","itemName":"Fire
>   One","thumbName":"FIREONE","dateAdded":"2016-11-04
>   14:10:32","renderTime":"25","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/FireOne-Scott/FireOne.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"53","itemId":"61617","itemName":"City
>   Spin","thumbName":"CITYSPIN","dateAdded":"2016-11-09
>   14:17:15","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/CitySpin-Scott/cityspin.aep","stillImageLocation":"8.933","categoryArray":["Church"],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"56","itemId":"15528","itemName":"Magic
>   Colors","thumbName":"MAGICCOLORS","dateAdded":"2016-11-10
>   13:10:26","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/MagicColors-Scott/MagicColors.aep","stillImageLocation":"3.966","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"61","itemId":"59239","itemName":"Quick
>   and Simple","thumbName":"QUICKNSIMPLE","dateAdded":"2016-11-14
>   11:42:09","renderTime":"15","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/QuickNSimple-Scott/QuickNSimple.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.033","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"62","itemId":"82460","itemName":"Fast
>   Blast","thumbName":"FASTBLAST","dateAdded":"2016-11-22
>   10:24:48","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/FastBlast-Scott/FastBlast.aep","stillImageLocation":"9.666","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"63","itemId":"83530","itemName":"Tunnel
>   Spin","thumbName":"TUNNELSPIN","dateAdded":"2016-12-02
>   13:09:06","renderTime":"20","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/tunnelSpin-Scott/tunnelSpin.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.9","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"64","itemId":"94148","itemName":"Sparkle
>   Splash","thumbName":"SPARKLESPLASH","dateAdded":"2016-12-20
>   11:23:26","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2016/SparkleSplash-Scott/SparkleSplash.aep","stillImageLocation":"6.1","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"69","itemId":"98640","itemName":"Gold
>   Bling","thumbName":"GOLDBLING","dateAdded":"2017-01-10
>   08:16:41","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/GoldBling-Joe/GoldBling.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"72","itemId":"94169","itemName":"Top
>   Racer","thumbName":"TOPRACER","dateAdded":"2017-02-15
>   09:46:14","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/TopRacer-Scott/TopRacer.aep","stillImageLocation":"7.833","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"73","itemId":"55871","itemName":"Desert
>   Sand","thumbName":"DESERTSAND","dateAdded":"2017-02-15
>   14:04:49","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/DesertSand-Scott/DesertSand.aep","stillImageLocation":"10.46","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"76","itemId":"18897","itemName":"Electric
>   Storm","thumbName":"ELECTRICSTORM","dateAdded":"2017-02-23
>   12:43:08","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/ElectricStorm-Scott/ElectricStorm.aep","stillImageLocation":"4.333","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"78","itemId":"24052","itemName":"Court
>   Smash","thumbName":"COURTSMASH","dateAdded":"2016-06-03
>   12:03:48","renderTime":"90","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/CourtSmash-Scott/CourtSmash.aep","stillImageLocation":"5.933","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"81","itemId":"43553","itemName":"Tile
>   Flip","thumbName":"TILEFLIP","dateAdded":"2017-04-25
>   16:40:41","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/TileFlip-Chris/TileFlip_Final/TileFlip_Final.aep","stillImageLocation":"5","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"88","itemId":"94677","itemName":"NEON
>   LIGHTS","thumbName":"NEONLIGHTS","dateAdded":"2017-04-28
>   10:06:23","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/NEONLIGHTS-Joe/NeonLights.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.53","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"89","itemId":"64305","itemName":"Engine
>   (Loop)","thumbName":"ENGINE","dateAdded":"2017-05-15
>   11:37:07","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/Engine-Scott/Engine.aep","stillImageLocation":"4.67","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"90","itemId":"11287","itemName":"Energy
>   Core","thumbName":"ENERGYCORE","dateAdded":"2017-05-22
>   13:08:40","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/EnergyCore-Scott/EnergyCore.aep","stillImageLocation":"6.73","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"91","itemId":"48745","itemName":"Football
>   Helmet","thumbName":"FOOTBALLHELMET","dateAdded":"2017-07-03
>   16:09:42","renderTime":"120","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/FootballHelmet-Scott/FootballHelmet.aep","stillImageLocation":"7","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"92","itemId":"85515","itemName":"Light
>   Shine","thumbName":"LIGHTSHINE","dateAdded":"2017-08-18
>   14:09:50","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/LightShine-Scott/LightShine.aep","stillImageLocation":"2","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"93","itemId":"61876","itemName":"Baseball
>   Dirt","thumbName":"BASEBALLDIRT","dateAdded":"2017-08-31
>   10:31:22","renderTime":"40","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/BaseballDirt-Scott/BaseballDirt.aep","stillImageLocation":"7.27","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"94","itemId":"48066","itemName":"Spooky","thumbName":"SPOOKY","dateAdded":"2017-09-01
>   13:58:36","renderTime":"15","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/Spooky-Jake/Spooky.aep","stillImageLocation":"2","categoryArray":["Sports"],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"95","itemId":"33584","itemName":"Get
>   Loud","thumbName":"GETLOUD","dateAdded":"2017-09-07
>   11:58:02","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/GetLoud-Scott/GetLoud.aep","stillImageLocation":"1.77","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"96","itemId":"21713","itemName":"STAR
>   BURST","thumbName":"STARBURST","dateAdded":"2017-10-19
>   18:20:29","renderTime":"15","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/StarBurst-Joe/StarBurst.aep","stillImageLocation":"0","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"97","itemId":"76554","itemName":"Magic
>   Twirl","thumbName":"MAGICFINAL","dateAdded":"2017-10-26
>   11:19:52","renderTime":"20","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/Magic-Lillie/Magic.aep","stillImageLocation":"825","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"98","itemId":"64452","itemName":"Sports
>   Car","thumbName":"SPORTSCAR","dateAdded":"2017-10-27
>   10:26:32","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/SportsCar-Scott/SportsCar.aep","stillImageLocation":"14.77","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"99","itemId":"15074","itemName":"Ice
>   Logo","thumbName":"ICELOGO","dateAdded":"2017-11-01
>   11:53:48","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/IceLogo-Scott/IceLogo.aep","stillImageLocation":"9.33","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":["LensFlare"]},{"id":"100","itemId":"95033","itemName":"Hot
>   Air Balloon","thumbName":"BALLOON","dateAdded":"2017-11-02
>   08:10:22","renderTime":"10","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/CreativeEngine/2017/Balloon-Lillie/Balloon.aep","stillImageLocation":"567","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"231","itemId":"bb39f253c6c237ecf5d86ced4e8bcdec","itemName":"test","thumbName":"TEST","dateAdded":"2018-09-28
>   18:35:08","renderTime":"4","tested":"0","projectPath":"M:/Projects/Generics/uploads/testLocation","stillImageLocation":"0.13","categoryArray":["Sports","Misc","Holiday"],"keywordArray":{"0":"LensFlare","2":"Snow","5":"Water"}}]

categories looks like this

> ["Holiday","Sports","Misc","Automotive","Retail","Financial","Church","Community","Food"]

keywords is the same as categories just different values

when a button is clicked selectedCategories begins to fill up with an array that looks like this :

> 0: "Holiday"

selectedKeywords like this (if its a keyword button instead of a category):

> 0: "lensFlare"

when a button gets pressed filteredTemplates looks like this in the vue inspector:

```
> filteredTemplateArray:Array[1] 0:Object categoryArray:Array[3]
> 0:"Sports" 1:"Misc" 2:"Holiday" dateAdded:"2018-09-28 18:35:08"
> id:"231" itemId:"bb39f253c6c237ecf5d86ced4e8bcdec" itemName:"test"
> keywordArray:Object
> projectPath:"M:/Projects/Generics/uploads/testLocation" renderTime:"4"
> stillImageLocation:"0.13" tested:"0" thumbName:"TEST"
```

I have the following method filtering the items when pressed but its not working how would ya'all change it so that all the items show up and items are filtered properly?

```
filter: function() {
  var filteredCategoryArray = [];
  var filteredKeywordArray = [];
  if(this.selectedCategories.length != 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.templateArray.length; i++) {
      for(var j = 0; j < this.selectedCategories.length; j++ ) {
        for(var k = 0; k < this.templateArray[i].categoryArray.length; k++ ) {
          if(this.templateArray[i].categoryArray[k] == this.selectedCategories[j]) {
            var arrayDuplicate = false;
            for(var l = 0; l < filteredKeywordArray.length; l++) {
              if(filteredCategoryArray[l].id == this.templateArray[i].id) {
                arrayDuplicate = true;
              }
            }
            if(arrayDuplicate == false) {
              filteredCategoryArray.push(this.templateArray[i]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.templateArray.length; i++){
      filteredCategoryArray.push(this.templateArray[i]);
    }
  }

  if(this.selectedKeywords.length != 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < filteredCategoryArray.length; i++) {
      for(var j = 0; j < this.selectedKeywords.length; j++ ) {
        for(var k = 0; k < filteredCategoryArray[i].keywordArray.length; k++ ) {
          if(filteredCategoryArray[i].keywordArray[k] == this.selectedKeywords[j]) {
            var arrayDuplicate = false;
            for(var l = 0; l < filteredKeywordArray.length; l++) {
              if(filteredKeywordArray[l].id == filteredCategoryArray[i].id) {
                arrayDuplicate = true;
              }
            }
            if(arrayDuplicate == false) {
              filteredKeywordArray.push(filteredCategoryArray[i]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    for(var i = 0; i < filteredCategoryArray.length; i++){
      filteredKeywordArray.push(filteredCategoryArray[i]);
    }
  }

  if(this.sortBy == "az") {
    filteredKeywordArray.sort(function(a,b) {
      if(a.itemName > b.itemName) {
        return 1;
      }
      if(a.itemName < b.itemName) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }

  if(this.sortBy == "dateAdded") {
    filteredKeywordArray.sort(function(a,b) {
      if(a.dateAdded < b.dateAdded) {
        return 1;
      }
      if(a.dateAdded > b.dateAdded) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }

  if(this.sortBy == "renderTime") {
    filteredKeywordArray.sort(function(a,b) {
      return parseInt(a.renderTime) - parseInt(b.renderTime);
    });
  }

  this.filteredTemplateArray = filteredKeywordArray;
  $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
},
```

heres the front end loop to show the videos

```
 <div class="row">
                <div v-cloak v-bind:key="template.itemId + '_' + index" v-for="(template, index) in searchResults" class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <video muted :src="'mysource'" controls preload="none" controlsList="nodownload nofullscreen" :poster="mysource" loop="loop"></video>
                        <div class="card-body">

                            <p class="card-title">{{template.itemName}}</p>
                            <!--end card-title-->
                            <p v-show="displayCount==0" class="card-text">Please create a display to customize</p>
                            <!--end user has no display card-text-->
                            <p v-show="displayCount>0" class="card-text">Custom Text, Custom Colors, Upload Logo</p>
                            <!--end user has display card text-->
                            <p class="card-text">{{template.renderTime}} minutes</p>
                            <a href="#" v-show="loggedIn==true && displayCount>0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Customize</a>
                            <!--logged in and has display button-->
                            <a href="#" v-show="loggedIn==false" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled>Customize</a>
                            <!--not logged in button-->
                            <a href="profile.php?showAddDisplayForm=1" v-show="loggedIn==true && displayCount==0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create A Display</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--end card-body-->
                    </div>
                    <!--end card-->
                </div>
                <!-- end col-md-4-->
            </div>
            <!--end row-->
```

Comment: Very minimal OP